Error when trying to create a Service Consumption Model in Eclipse
I am trying to create a Service Consumption Model with OData in Eclipse and I get following error after choosing the EDMX file.

Error while parsing an XML stream: 'failed to change codepage'


I got the EDMX file from the SAP API spezification.

Can anyone help me? What is the issue here?
Best regards

Which codepage? Please show the EDMX file. Maybe there is more in the error log: if so, please go to the Error Log view, select the error (do not open it, just select the row), hit Ctrl+C and paste everything (make sure it starts with eclipse.buildId= and that nothing has been cropped; if you anonymize something say so) into your question formatted as Sample Code (indented by four spaces to keep line breaks and characters like <). If more errors have been logged recently, first delete the error log and reproduce your issue.
